# How to access environment variable from html or js in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Here set environment variables using

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
```

I want to display some values in UI. Is there any way to access values from `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass variable you need in a context like that

```py
import os

from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', context={
        'YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE': os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE')
    })
```

And then in `path/to/template.html` you can access that context variable. But for JS files it can get a bit tricky, although you can use `{{ template syntax }}` to place your variable value inside `<script>` tag in HTML, but it is common to have JS externally (linked from HTML). Then you can do something like that in your HTML.

```html
<input id="YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE" value="{{ YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE }}" type="hidden" />
```

And then in your JS file

```js
let hiddenInput = document.getElementById("YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE");
let yourEnvVariableValue = hiddenInput.value;
```

#### Edit: Accesing env variables without passing it to context

You can define your own [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/). Example:

```py
# your_app/templatetags/env_extras.py

import os
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_env_var(key):
    return os.environ.get(key)
```

And then in your HTML:

```html
{% load env_extras %}

<input id="YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE" value="{% get_env_var 'YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE' %}" type="hidden" />
```

P.S. You might need to reload your server manually in order for custom tag to take effect.

Comment: Thanx , But is there any way to access those environment variables directly without adding those in the context...

Comment: SinethLakshitha sorry for late answer. Yes you can. I've edited my answer